# How to get an element from object of type predicate in Typescript Angular

Tags: typescript

Hope this makes sense, but i'm trying to understand how to get the element that exists on an object of a certain type, but is defined as a type predicate.

Ie, `Team` is defined as

```
let team$: Observable<ErrorModel | Team>
```

and so the result of a successful call to this observable is type `Team` and this has a `code`, whereas the `ErrorModel` does not and therefore typescript linter says `code does not exist on type ErrorModel | Team`

So basically

```
return team$.subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.code);
}
```

How do I say `response.code` in this case - even if I do a `typeof`, it still will give me that lint error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the result can be either a `Team` or an `ErrorModel` the compiler will only let you access common properties of the two. You can narrow the type of the `response` using a type guard. In this case an `in` type-guard:

```
team$.subscribe(response => {
  if ('code' in response) console.log(response.code);
});
```